# print sql response to html with jinja without knowing how tables are stored

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlite, jinja2

I want to read a database entry for example:
SELECT * FROM users;
then output the entire table to a html striped table with headers properly displayed, here is my jinja code, the schema part pulls out the database headers as columns properly, but the data columns show as empty.

```
{% if select==1 %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for i in schema %}
                <th>{{ i }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for i in rows %}
        <tr>
            {%for k in schema %}
                <th>{{ i[schema] }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
{% elif select==2 %}
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" type="text"/>
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="zip_code" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text"/>
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
{% endif %}
```

Here is my python code, schema simply makes a list with only the column names of the database:

```
    if request.form['submit']== 'query':
        select=1
        a=db.execute("PRAGMA table_info(users)")
        schema=[]
        for i in a:
            schema.append(i['name'])
        rows=db.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
```

Comment: I didn't get your question! do you mean you want to read entire database table into html using jinja2 without knowing how many headers you have?